# How to make an array formula with two variables

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a problem with my array formula which contains two variables. I want to make a ArrayFormula to count filled cells in columns in my table generated in the new sheet. The table has number of columns depending of nos value. Cloumns are named "Tabela_" & name & "[Substancja1] etc. I want to sum all of filled cells in those columns. I think I have to fix something in syntax, either of formula or code. I made another array formula in Range("C5") and it works. I tried with quotation marks ("") between string and variables but it didn't work. Please, help me.
This code generate an error 1004: impossible to set the FormulaArray in Range class.
Sheet for example:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AitFOK70PUC7wx_7vnh5EqkdJLfe

```
Sub newSheet()

    Dim name As String
    Dim nos As Integer
    Dim formRozp As String

name = InputBox("blabla:", "Add item")
nos = InputBox("blabla" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Range: 1-10.", "Add item")

Range("C5").FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(Tabela_" & nazwa & "[Data]="""",0,1))"

formRozp = "=SUM(IF(Tabela_" & name & "[Substancja1]="""";0;1))"

For nos = 2 To nos - 1
    formRozp = formRozp & "+SUM(IF(Tabela_" & name & "[Substancja" & 
    nos & "]="""";0;1))"
Next nos

Range("C3").FormulaArray = formRozp
```

The code generate the formula for name=b5 and nos=3 but it isn't working.

```
=SUM(IF(Tabela_b5[Substancja1]="";0;1))+SUM(IF(Tabela_b5[Substancja2]="";0;1))+SUM(IF(Tabela_b5[Substancja3]="";0;1))
```

Comment: One problem can be solved in many ways. So, post your sample data explain problem, then show your effort and desired result. This will help you to get best solution. It seems your problem may be solve by `=SUMIFS()`.

Comment: I edited my post and posted a link to sample of sheet with my data.
I tried with =sumifs() but also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard for me to test with English version, but there might be a translation problem.
You might try, with your version of code, first writing it in your language, and then using something like:

```
.FormulaLocal = "my_formula"
.FormulaArray = .Formula
```

However, I think a simpler formula to count the filled cells would be something like:

```
=SUM(COUNTA(Tabela_b6[Substancja1],Tabela_b6[Substancja2],Tabela_b6[Substancja3]))
```

It is a non-array formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
' If column's name is  "Tabela_" & name & "[Substancja1]"
Range("C5").FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF([@[Tabela_" & name & "Substancja1]]="""",0,1))"

' If column's name is Data and table name is Tabela_" & name
Range("C5").FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(Tabela_" & name & "[@[Data]]="""",0,1))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ron for your concept. I changed the functions and it works for me:
The final formula: `=SUM(CountA(Tabela_b11[Substancja1],Tabela_b11[Substancja2],Tabela_b11[Substancja3],Tabela_b11[Substancja4]))`

the code:

```
formRozp = "=SUM(CountA(Tabela_" & nazwa & "[Substancja1]))"
For nos = 2 To nos - 1
    formRozp = Replace(formRozp, "))", ",Tabela_" & name & "[Substancja" & nos & "]))")
Next nos

Range("C3").formula = formRozp
```

I use the polish version so maybe that could be a problem. But now it works so I am happy. Thanks a lot!